# Como mudar a cor de fundo do Fragmento de texto?

Tags: html, url

Eu estou criando **Fragmentos de textos** (*Text Fragment*).

Os fragmentos de texto que estou me referindo são os links no formato `#:~:text=textStart,textEnd` que quando clicados, além de levar a pessoa ao site, destacam o texto buscado com uma cor de fundo.

Eu gostaria de mudar a cor padrão de fundo do texto selecionado que é "amarelo" para uma outra cor que esteja relacionada ao visual do meu site.

Como, por exemplo, ao acessar o site do **MDN** será selecionado o texto com o fundo "roxo claro" no Google Chrome:

> Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is an application-layer protocol for transmitting hypermedia documents, such as HTML.

Este é o link que utilizei para o exemplo acima:

```
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/#:~:text=Hypertext%20Transfer%20Protocol%20(HTTP),%20HTML.
```

**OBS:** eu não coloquei  o código, porque aparentemente aqui no SOpt não funciona, por tanto, terá que copiar o link e pesquisar. Esta é a imagem do resultado do exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu posso alterar a cor de fundo do fragmento de texto quando o link for acessado e o texto destacado, usando apenas CSS ou eu terei que utilizar JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a MDN, o fragmento é estilizado pelo pseudo-elemento `::target-text`

#### Documentação:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::target-text

#### Exemplo de uso:

```
::target-text {
   background: #ff00ff;
}
```

Importante notar que ainda é um draft, ainda pode mudar a especificação, e pode até não ser adotado oficialmente.